# possible cyclic group from fundamental theorem of finite abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Question: 
>   Give a representative of each Isomorphism class of Abelian group of order 225.
>   Which ones are cyclic?

By the Fundamental theorem of finite abelian group:

$\left | G \right |=225=3^{2}5^2$

Now, the possible isomorphism are

$G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{3}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{3}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{5}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{5},
\mathbb{Z}_{9}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{25},
\mathbb{Z}_{9}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{5}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{5},
\mathbb{Z}_{3}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{3}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{25}$

Here's my confusion:

My solution indicates the **ONLY** cyclic groups to be $\mathbb{Z}_{9}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{25}$,
but from the theorem of external direct product of cyclic group, this cannot be the only cyclic group since

for all cyclic groups G and H, $G \otimes H$ are cyclic IFF $GCD\left ( \left | H \right |,\left | G \right | \right )$ are coprime.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All your $\otimes$ (\otimes) should be $\oplus$ (\oplus).

Comment: And why would that mean it was not cyclic? Those integers are indeed coprime (also, you should use either $\times$ or $\oplus$ for direct product, rather than $\otimes$).

Comment: Yes agreed. I've edited the critical portion.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one cyclic group of any order. $9$ and $25$ are coprime. $\mathbb Z_9\oplus\mathbb Z_{25}$ is cyclic.

I can only guess that $\oplus$ or $\times$ is what you mean, but one of them must be because $\otimes$ is nonsensical in this case, as $\mathbb Z_9\otimes\mathbb Z_{25}=0$.

Comment: But Gcd(3,3,5,5) are co prime too

Comment: @Mathematicing Your question seems to be asking for possible cyclic groups. You'd be right if it was asking for all possible abelian groups.

Comment: @Mathe $3$ and $3$ are not coprime.

Comment: @MattSamuel Mathematical returns GCD[3, 3, 5, 5]=1

Comment: @Mathe what's relevant is that the numbers be *pairwise* coprime. You would need $\gcd(3,3)=\gcd(3,5)=\gcd(3,5)=\gcd(3,5)=\gcd(3,5)=\gcd(5,5)=1$, which is not true (the duplicates are all pairs).

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes. Horrible notation that I employed.

Comment: @florence The question asks which ones are cyclic. Allow me to indicate that portion in the OP.

Comment: @MattSamuel I do not yet understand. $\mathbb{Z}_{9} , \mathbb{Z}_{5}, ,\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ are cyclic groups. 
In particular, their orders, respectively 
are 9,5,5.
They are co prime to one another. 
So shouldn't their direct product also be cyclic?

Comment: @Mathematicing no, those numbers are not pairwise coprime.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Would you mind expanding on the concept of pairwise coprime in the context of the OP? Thanks.

Comment: @Mathematicing There is nothing to expand in that context. The definition is not related to this, you just seem to keep forgetting the "pairwise" part, which was already spelled out above.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Got it!